# Local maven dependencies for OpenAM 12

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, openam, forgerock

I need to compile OpenAM 12.0.0 from source code using maven, but since Forgerock has blocked access to maven.forgerock.org, the dependencies cannot be fetched online any more, and OpenAM won't compile :'(

A solution would be to download the maven dependencies locally and configure maven to not update local dependencies (using `<updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>` in `settings.xml`).

I found following post which gives dependencies for OpenAM 13 (https://forum.forgerock.com/topic/maven-forgerock-org-problem/#post-16583) but I need the same for OpenAM 12.

Does anyone has thoses dependencies and can package them in an archive, or does anyone hosts an maven repository which contains the required dependencies ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Forgerock closed their source code, so OpenAM now maintained by [Open Identity Platform community](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform). You can download OpenAM source code from community's [repository](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM) and get latest release from [here](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/releases)